# Python Jupyter notebook, call a bash function declared in a different cell

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I know that different cells in a *Python* Jupiter notebook are executed in different subshells. However, I would want to declare a bash function in one shell and the call it from other multiple cells:

In [1]:

```sh
%%bash
function my_func {
    #...
}
```

In [2]:

```
%%bash
my_func
```

In [3]:

```
%%bash
my_func
```

Is there some way to do it? I don't want to put the function in ~/.bashrc for example because I want it to be a part of the notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the inline [alias magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) to reference `my_func`. Here is a quick example of doing multiple commands in a single `alias` and passing a parameter if needed.

[image]

Another way would be to use the python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. You would define the subprocess and call it as needed.